# Remove number in URL

Tags: pages, urls

I'm trying to use WordPress to make a web page. I made a "Contact" page, but for some reason it didn't show up. WordPress kept saying it couldn't find it. So I deleted it and made a new one called the same thing, "Contact". Now the Contact page works, but it has a `-2` in the URL. I want to make it say `http://www.dragonavionics.com/contact/` instead of `http://www.dragonavionics.com/contact-2/`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete a post, it merely gets put into the "trash" and retains its slug.  When you created the "new" contact page, the slug "contact" was already in use by the original contact post that is in the trash.

Go into your posts on the dashboard and click on the "Trash" link near the top of the post listing.  Once in the Trash area, permanently delete the original contact post.

You can now go back into the "new" contact post, edit the slug near the top of the post, and remove the extra -2 that was added to it.  Click OK and save the post.  It should now have the slug contact instead of contact-2

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly right. Also, thank you for introducing me to the term "slug". http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Slug My searching didn't find an answer because I didn't understand the term slug.

Comment: @kmort:  Glad I could help and glad you learned something...that's the purpose of the forum. :-)